# How do I compare a row value in one column to all other rows in a different column within a group?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe that has the columns: user_id, product_id, created_at and removed_at. 
I want add a boolean column "is_switch" that is True if, for a given user, the timestamp for created_at is the within a timedelta (let's say 1 second) as a removed_at for any other row in that user group. How can I do this without iterating over every row, or is that the appropriate way to do it?

I am trying to write a custom function to use with .apply that will run on each user group, but i'm not sure how to compare rows with all the other rows in one shot.

```py
# Code to create sample data frame. 
# the below are just timestamps that are within a second of each other.

import datetime

a = datetime.datetime.now()
a2 = a-datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
b = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=4)
b2 = b-datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
c = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=40)
c2 = c - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
d = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=30)
d2 = d - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
e = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=60)
e2 = e - datetime.timedelta(seconds=1)
f = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=100)
g = datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=99)

df = pd.DataFrame(
{"user_id" : [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4],
"product_id" : [100, 101, 102, 101, 102, 104, 105, 106, 107, 105, 106, 107],
"created_at" : [a, a, b, c, d, c, f, f, e2, f, f, d],
"removed_at" : ['NaT', b2, 'NaT', d2, 'NaT', 'NaT', e, g, 'NaT', e2, g, b]},
index = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11])
df

print(df)
```

yields this:

```py
        user_id  product_id                 created_at                 removed_at
0         0         100 2019-08-04 09:15:05.200981                        NaT
1         1         101 2019-08-04 09:15:05.200981 2019-07-31 09:15:04.201063
2         1         102 2019-07-31 09:15:05.201063                        NaT
3         2         101 2019-06-25 09:15:05.201121 2019-07-05 09:15:04.201179
4         2         102 2019-07-05 09:15:05.201179                        NaT
5         2         104 2019-06-25 09:15:05.201121                        NaT
6         3         105 2019-04-26 09:15:05.201290 2019-06-05 09:15:05.201235
7         3         106 2019-04-26 09:15:05.201290 2019-04-27 09:15:05.201324
8         3         107 2019-06-05 09:15:04.201235                        NaT
9         4         105 2019-04-26 09:15:05.201290 2019-06-05 09:15:04.201235
10        4         106 2019-04-26 09:15:05.201290 2019-04-27 09:15:05.201324
11        4         107 2019-07-05 09:15:05.201179 2019-07-31 09:15:05.201063
```

So I currently have something like this:

```py
group_by_user = df.groupby('user_id')

def calculate_is_switch(grp):
    # What goes here? how can i do it without iterating over each row?

# group_by_user.apply(calculate_is_switch)
```

I would like to add the 'is_switch' column so the output is this:

```py
    user_id  product_id                 created_at                 removed_at  \
0         0         100 2019-08-04 09:15:05.200981                        NaT   
1         1         101 2019-08-04 09:15:05.200981 2019-07-31 09:15:04.201063   
2         1         102 2019-07-31 09:15:05.201063                        NaT   
3         2         101 2019-06-25 09:15:05.201121 2019-07-05 09:15:04.201179   
4         2         102 2019-07-05 09:15:05.201179                        NaT   
5         2         104 2019-06-25 09:15:05.201121                        NaT   
6         3         105 2019-04-26 09:15:05.201290 2019-06-05 09:15:05.201235   
7         3         106 2019-04-26 09:15:05.201290 2019-04-27 09:15:05.201324   
8         3         107 2019-06-05 09:15:04.201235                        NaT   
9         4         105 2019-04-26 09:15:05.201290 2019-06-05 09:15:04.201235   
10        4         106 2019-04-26 09:15:05.201290 2019-04-27 09:15:05.201324   
11        4         107 2019-07-05 09:15:05.201179 2019-07-31 09:15:05.201063   

    is_switch  
0       False  
1       False  
2        True  
3       False  
4        True  
5       False  
6       False  
7       False  
8        True  
9       False  
10      False  
11      False
```

Comment: there is always first value in `removed_at` per groups (if exist per groups) ?

Comment: Can it happen that there is more than 1 value in `removed_at` per `user_id`?

Comment: @Erfan Yes, user can remove multiple products at different times

Comment: @dryOlive - Can you create [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) with repeated `removed_at` per `user_id` ?

Comment: You should edit your data to show that situation where a user has multiple `removed_at` dates. Now each user only has one.

Comment: @jezrael Not necessarily - but if I sort by removed_at ascending then it would always be the first value right?

Comment: @dryOlive - it working if only one value per group...

Comment: @dryOlive - answer was edited. Please check it.

Comment: @jezrael the output doesn't match the desired one, there doesn't have to be at least one True per user group. If the user subscribes at a time outside of the 1sec window it is not considered a switch

Comment: @dryOlive - Sorry, please change `y = np.any((np.abs(y).astype(np.int64) <= val.value), axis=1)` to `y = np.any((np.abs(y).astype(np.int64) <= val.value), axis=0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) with custom function - first replace missing values by some default value datetime, e.g. `Timestamp.min` and then per groups compare columns with broadcasting - all values with `created_at` by `removed_at`, get absolute values, compare by 1 second and return at least one `True` per rows by `any`:

```
val = pd.Timedelta(1, unit='s')

def f(x):
    y = x['created_at'].values - x['removed_at'].values[:, None]
    y = np.any((np.abs(y).astype(np.int64) <= val.value), axis=0)

    return pd.Series(y, index=x.index)

df['is_switch'] = (df.assign(removed_at = df['removed_at'].fillna(pd.Timestamp.min))
                     .groupby('user_id')
                     .apply(f)
                     .reset_index(level=0, drop=True))
```

---

```
print(df)
    user_id  product_id                 created_at                 removed_at  \
0         0         100 2019-08-04 16:22:39.309093                        NaT   
1         1         101 2019-08-04 16:22:39.309093 2019-07-31 16:22:38.309093   
2         1         102 2019-07-31 16:22:39.309093                        NaT   
3         2         101 2019-06-25 16:22:39.309093 2019-07-05 16:22:38.309093   
4         2         102 2019-07-05 16:22:39.309093                        NaT   
5         2         104 2019-06-25 16:22:39.309093                        NaT   
6         3         105 2019-04-26 16:22:39.309093 2019-06-05 16:22:39.309093   
7         3         106 2019-04-26 16:22:39.309093 2019-04-27 16:22:39.309093   
8         3         107 2019-06-05 16:22:38.309093                        NaT   
9         4         105 2019-04-26 16:22:39.309093 2019-06-05 16:22:38.309093   
10        4         106 2019-04-26 16:22:39.309093 2019-04-27 16:22:39.309093   
11        4         107 2019-07-05 16:22:39.309093 2019-07-31 16:22:39.309093   

    is_switch  
0       False  
1       False  
2        True  
3       False  
4        True  
5       False  
6       False  
7       False  
8        True  
9       False  
10      False  
11      False
```

Comment: I think this question is more complicated, since a user can have multiple `removed_at` dates. So `transform('first')` would not work in this case

Answer (score 0):

One-liner would be:

```
print(~df['created_at'].sub(df.groupby('user_id').transform('first')['created_at']).dt.days.between(-1, 1))
```

Output:

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
5    False
Name: created_at, dtype: bool
```